# Chrome extensions how to access a global variable set in a script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have this in a chrome extension pulled in js file.

```
  function App() { alert(1) }
```

When I right click -> show console and try to fire the method the method App is not defined.

Why ? Something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your console is working in the context of the plugin and not the page. There's a select box on the bottom of your console. Change 'page context' to 'chrome extension'

[image: chrome page context]

Comment: I cannot find the bottom select box you are talking about, where is it located exactly? Btw, the var doesnt really matter here, since I am making it global using window.App ... but I will update my question to be more clear

Comment: Do you see 'All, Errors, Warnings, Logs' on the bottom of the console?

Comment: Yes I do! Do you have a print screen?

Comment: Uploaded print screen. If you don't see <page context>, try close and open the console

Comment: Thanks! I had to close and open the console. It works :) Thanks!! :D

Comment: Damn annoying that on refresh I have to keep redoing these steps, including close and reopen console..

Comment: Yep same here. Seems like a bug to me